# How to generate a JSON Schema?

Tags: node.js, ajv

I would like to generate a schema from a json object.

```
 var GenerateSchema = require('generate-schema')
 var schema = GenerateSchema.json(request.body);
```

Request.Body

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          102,
          0.5
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            102,
            0
          ],
          [
            103,
            1
          ],
          [
            104,
            0
          ],
          [
            105,
            1
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              100,
              0
            ],
            [
              101,
              0
            ],
            [
              101,
              1
            ],
            [
              100,
              1
            ],
            [
              100,
              0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": {
          "this": "that"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Schema generated from the request.body

```
{
  "$id": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Product",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "features": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "coordinates": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "oneOf": [
                    {
                      "type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "number"
                    }
                  ],
                  "type": "array"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "properties": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "prop0": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "prop1": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "this": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "type",
          "geometry",
          "properties"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Schema validation with Ajv

```
[
  {
    keyword: 'type',
    dataPath: '.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0]',
    schemaPath: '#/properties/features/items/properties/geometry/properties/coordinates/items/type',
    params: { type: 'array' },
    message: 'should be array'
  }
]
```

Why Ajv detects an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want `coordinates` to be either an array of numbers *or* an array of arrays of numbers then this schema doesn't look right to me:

```
"coordinates": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "type": "number"
      },
      {
        "type": "number"
      },
      {
        "type": "number"
      },
      {
        "type": "number"
      },
      {
        "type": "number"
      }
    ],
    "type": "array"
  }
}
```

You would typically use `oneOf` to choose between different schemas but the `oneOf` here says:

- it can be a number
- or a number
- or a number
- or a number
- or a number

But then ultimately it doesn't matter because you have a `{"type": "array"}` in the end that seems to override everything which would explain why it fails for `{"coordinates": [102, 0.5]}` because that is not an array of arrays.

It seems that what you're looking for is more along the lines of: (untested)

```
"coordinates": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "oneOf": [
      { "type": "number" },
      { "type": "array", "items": { "type": "number"} }
    ]
  }
}
```

Which reads:

> items in a `coordinates` array can be either "numbers" or "arrays of numbers".

I think that your `generate-schema` package got this wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer with QuickType library